# First try at a dotnetcore ASP.Net: WebHostBuilder error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, centos7

Under `linux`, using the latest `dotnetcore`

```
[idf@localhost dot-net-core-centos-7-master]$ dotnet --version
1.0.4
[idf@localhost dot-net-core-centos-7-master]$
```

I am getting an erron on this simple application. What am I missing?

The **.csproj** file

```
[idf@localhost dot-net-core-centos-7-master]$ more dot-net-core-centos-7-master.csproj 
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
      <Version>1.0.0-alpha-20161104-2</Version>
      <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
      <Version>1.0.0-alpha-20161104-2</Version>
      <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App">
      <Version>1.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc">
      <Version>1.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
[idf@localhost dot-net-core-centos-7-master]$
```

**project.json**:

```
[idf@localhost dot-net-core-centos-7-master]$ more project.json
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  },
}
```

The **Program.cs**

```
[idf@localhost dot-net-core-centos-7-master]$ more Program.cs 
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;


namespace aspnetcoreapp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {                
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls("http://*:80/")
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
[idf@localhost dot-net-core-centos-7-master]$ more Startup.cs 

using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace aspnetcoreapp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.Run(context =>
            {
                return context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello from ASP.NET Core!");
            });
        }
    }
}

[idf@localhost dot-net-core-centos-7-master]$
```

When I try to run it I get a runtime error:

```
[idf@localhost dot-net-core-centos-7-master]$ dotnet run
/home/idf/dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets(101,5): warning : A PackageReference for 'Microsoft.NETCore.App' was included in your project. This package is implicitly referenced by the .NET SDK and you do not typically need to reference it from your project. For more information, see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicitrefs [/home/idf/dotnet_progs/dot-net-core-centos-7-master/dot-net-core-centos-7-master.csproj]
Program.cs(14,28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'WebHostBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/home/idf/dotnet_progs/dot-net-core-centos-7-master/dot-net-core-centos-7-master.csproj]
Program.cs(20,18): error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'handler' of 'RunExtensions.Run(IApplicationBuilder, RequestDelegate)' [/home/idf/dotnet_progs/dot-net-core-centos-7-master/dot-net-core-centos-7-master.csproj]

The build failed. Please fix the build errors and run again.
[idf@localhost dot-net-core-centos-7-master]$ ls
```

Comment: What version of dotnet are you running? `dotnet --version`

Comment: @kimbaudi 1.0.4

Comment: ok just wanted to know. i'm wondering why you have both `.csproj` file and `project.json` file. maybe you migrated from `project.json` to `.csproj`. I think you should first backup `project.json` somewhere and remove it from your web app. i'll post an answer that i hope will help you.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I  was confused because it seems that the new dotnet no longer uses project.json. It appears you have verified this.

Comment: Yeah, i would first get rid of `project.json` (but back it up first just in case). I'll post what I think the contents of your `.csproj` should be right now. hopefully that should fix the build.

Comment: Ok. I removed both the project.json and the project.lock.json out of the directory and tried again. Still same problem.

Comment: you still need to at least remove reference to `Microsoft.NETCore.App` in your `.csproj` file. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the fact that you are referencing `Microsoft.NETCore.App` in your `.csproj` and `project.json` file. Looking at the `.csproj` file for one of my .NET Core web app, I don't see any reference to `Microsoft.NETCore.App`. So my suggestion is for you to first backup the copy of the original somewhere and then remove the lines in your `.csproj` and `project.json` files that reference `Microsoft.NETCore.App`. I find it odd that you have both a `.csproj` file and `project.json` file.

Here is what I think your `.csproj` file should look like:

**.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Once you update your `.csproj` file and safely remove `project.json`, I would do `dotnet clean` to clean your build output and then `dotnet build` to see if everything is ok. If so, you should be able to `dotnet run` just fine.

Answer (score 0):

kimbaudi is right.

After some fiddeling with the paketmanager from hell (Nuget) my program throw some weired exceptions. I had installed "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" via Nuget-Manager, but weiredly "Microsoft.AspNetCore" was removed. After reinstalling it all works fine again.